# Convert Dynamic HTML to PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf, html-to-pdf

I am using jsp to display html and css3. When I display my html page, I will have a pdf icon, if that is clicked then I need to convert the html page to pdf and download it.

I have tried using XMLWorker, but there I need to send my html link through URL. But its saying this exception, "**RuntimeWorkerException: Invalid nested tag head found, expected closing tag script.**". I cant hard code my html.

Is there any easy way where I just click the button, so that all the html content from page can be downloaded as pdf? As I am new to programming I couldn't fix this issue. I went through other question but there were no clear explanation regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsPDF](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/) to convert HTML to PDF online, just using JavaScript on the client side.

The initialisation code is very simple:

```
// You'll need to make your image into a Data URL
// Use http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker
var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';

var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text(35, 25, "Octonyan loves jsPDF");
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 180);
```

This is a HTML5 client-side solution for generating PDFs.